# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un botón tenga un marco igual a su contenido?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un boton que le definí como *background* una imagen circular. El problema que tengo es que su marco (osea el espacio que ocupa), es el rectángulo que lo rodea. Esto me trae el inconveniente de que si un usuario (por esas razones), hace click fuera pero muy cerca de mi botón circular, este mismo se ejecuta y no quiero que sea así.

La verdad es que desconozco como se puede solucionar este problema, si se puede agregar una propiedad al botón para que su marco se adapte al contenido de su *background* o si se puede solucionar desde la clase java.

Cualquier respuesta se agradece

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiarle la forma a un botón necesitas un XML que defina la forma de ese botón:
Primero, creas un nuevo xml en res/drawable (por ejemplo, bt_circle) y en él defines la forma que quieres que tenga tu botón, así como sus colores, etc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
 <shape android:shape="oval">
 <solid android:color="@color/Primary" />
 <size android:width="30dp" android:height="30dp" />
 </shape>
 </item>
</selector>
```

Luego basta con que le asignes ese drawable al botón `android:background="@drawable/bt_circle"`

Con eso debería estar listo tu botón circular

Comment: No es la respuesta que estaba buscando. Lo explico de otra forma: Necesito que mi boton ocupe el mismo espacio tanto de la vista *Design* como la de *Blueprint*, ya que por defecto, el espacio que ocupa el boton (ya sea circular o no) es siempre un rectángulo que lo rodea.

Comment: Vale, ya te entiendo @Lucas, disculpa. Lo que quieres hacer diría que es "imposible", cualquier imagen en android siempre será un cuadrado/rectángulo, aunque tenga bordes transparentes. Lo que puedes hacer es que tu botón implemente [OnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html), coger las coordenadas del evento y mirar si están dentro del área de tu imagen... es la única manera que se me ocurre.

Comment: Ah perfecto, muchas gracias por la aclaración. Voy a hacerlo como me indicaste.